# TG бот на Python. Ошибка {"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Решил сделать простого TG повторяющего бота. Запускаю в командной строке и получаю это:
{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}
Так понимаю он не может найти мой токен.
Вот код:

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def repeat(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Уберите кавычки:
`bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)`

Comment: Блин точно. Но все равно ошибка осталась

Answer (score 0):

404 возникает при неверном токене. Уберите кавычки в

> bot = telebot.Telebot(config.TOKEN)

Проверьте токен, и является ли он строкой в config.

Comment: Вся соль в том, то что даже через специальную ссылку для проверки существования токена, мне выводится что-то типа json с ошибкой.

Comment: @Babromych Вы уверены что верно скопировали токен?

Comment: Да уверен......